# what is the order of insertion of values in numpy.insert command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to understand how the `numpy.insert` command works in a 2D array. I know that the third value in this command is the value that we want to insert but what does `[2,2]` indicate? When I print the result of the second example, `[0,1]` appears along the column axis before the second column but in the first example `[0,1]` appears along the row axis. I'm unable to understand this behavior. Can someone please guide me?

```
`#first example
s=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
print s
t= numpy.insert(s, [2,2], [0,1],axis=1)
print t
#second example
a=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
b=numpy.insert(a, 2,[0,1],axis=1)`
```

Comment: did you read this ? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Comment: On [so], we expect users to [research before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Yes i read the docs. But it explains one dimensional array.  I couldn't understand this for 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [606]: s=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
In [607]: np.insert(s,[2,2],[10,11], axis=1)
Out[607]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 10, 11,  3],
       [ 2,  3, 10, 11,  4]])
```

So this is putting the `10` at column 2, and `11` at column 2 as well.  It's done all at once, not iteratively.

```
In [608]: np.insert(s,[0,1],[10,11], axis=1)
Out[608]: 
array([[10,  1, 11,  2,  3],
       [10,  2, 11,  3,  4]])
```

It may be more evident here, where `10` is at the 0th column, and `11` at the original `1th`.

Note it's inserting by column, so 2d with axis=1 behaves the same as a 1d without axis.

An equivalent list insertion is:

```
In [626]: alist = [1,2,3]
In [627]: for i,v in zip([1,0],[11,10]): alist[i:i] = [v]     
In [628]: alist
Out[628]: [10, 1, 11, 2, 3]
```

Notice that I start from the end.  Otherwise insert

With a scalar both values are inserted in one column:

```
In [610]: np.insert(s,2,[10,11], axis=1)
Out[610]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 10,  3],
       [ 2,  3, 11,  4]])
```

With a single element list, `[2]` the effect is the same as with `[2,2]`:

```
In [614]: np.insert(s,[2],[10,11], axis=1)
Out[614]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 10, 11,  3],
       [ 2,  3, 10, 11,  4]])
```

The documentation talks a the difference between indexing with a scalar and a list.

There also seems to be a kind of broadcasting going on.  That single `[2]` can broadcast with the double `[10,11]`.  Conversely the documentation has an example

```
np.insert(x, (1,3), 999, axis=1)
```

Other examples of broadcasting between indices and values:

```
In [636]: np.insert(s,[0,1,2,3],[[10],[11]], axis=1)
Out[636]: 
array([[10,  1, 10,  2, 10,  3, 10],
       [11,  2, 11,  3, 11,  4, 11]])
In [639]: np.insert(s,[0,1,2,3],[10,11,12,13], axis=1)
....
In [640]: np.insert(s,[0,1,2,3],np.arange(8).reshape(2,-1), axis=1)
...
```

In fact if you mismatch shapes you can get a broadcasting error:

```
In [638]: np.insert(s,[0,1,2,3],[10,11,12], axis=1)
   ...
   5104     slobj[axis] = indices
   5105     slobj2[axis] = old_mask
-> 5106     new[slobj] = values
   5107     new[slobj2] = arr
   5108 

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (4,2)
```

It has constructed a `slobj` indexing tuple, and tries to put the `values` there.  `slobj2` is the indexing tuple where the original values belong.

In a sense `np.insert` is hard to understand because it tries to be so powerful, handling many different combinations of indices and values.  It is pure Python, so anything it can do, you can also do.  Just create a target array of the right size, and copy values to the right slots.

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**:

```
numpy.insert(arr, obj, values, axis=None)
```

**Example 1**:

```
t = numpy.insert(s, [2, 3], [0, 1], axis=1)
```

- `s` is input numpy array.
- `[2, 3]` specifies where you need to insert values. First `2` means
  your first value is to be inserted before 2nd index. Next `3` means insert second value before 3rd index. *(Here, I used second value as `3` instead of `2` in your example only to make you understand better.)*
- `[0, 1]` are the values you are inserting. Here, `0` will be inserted before 2nd index and `1` before 3rd index.
- `axis=1` means insert as column.

**Example 2**:

```
b = numpy.insert(a, 2, [0, 1], axis=1)
```

- `a` is input numpy array.
- `2` means insert before 2nd position.
- `[0, 1]` means insert `0` on first row and `1` on second row.
- `axis=1` means insert as column.

*Note*: If `axis=0`, values will be inserted as a new row. If axis is not given or set to `None`, the array is flattened before insertion.

For detailed information, you could always refer to docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html).